# ¿Como mostrar un mensaje de error cuando ya existe un dato en la base de datos usando Saripaar?

Tags: java, android, firebase, login

Estoy creando una aplicación y estoy haciendo el Login y registro. En estos dos estoy usando la librería Saripaar para mostrar distintos mensajes de error (Campos vacíos, el formato de correo no es valido, la contraseña debe tener 8 caracteres, etc), y los muestro en un mensaje pequeño debajo de cada campo de texto. Para ello utilizo las anotaciones que vienen en la librería, hasta ahí todo bien. Pero ahora estoy teniendo dificultades para mostrar un mensaje de error cuando ya existe un correo y un ID en la base de datos, estoy usando Firebase Firestore.

Estoy aprendiendo a usar esto, y estoy un poco perdido en esto de crear un mensaje personalizado según algo que yo quiera evaluar, en este caso quiero comprobar si existe el correo y el id en Firestore, y mostrar su mensaje de error correspondiente.

Este es el Fragment donde realizo el login, y tengo las anotaciones correspondientes para el correo y contraseña

```
public class SignInWithEmailAndPasswordFragment extends Fragment {

@BindView(R.id.email_container)
TextInputLayout emailContainer;
@BindView(R.id.password_container)
TextInputLayout passwordContainer;

@NotEmpty(sequence = 1, messageResId = R.string.empty_field_error_message)
@Email(sequence = 2, messageResId = R.string.invalid_email_error_message)
@BindView(R.id.email)
TextInputEditText email;

@NotEmpty(sequence = 1, messageResId = R.string.empty_field_error_message)
@Password(sequence = 2, messageResId = R.string.password_error_message, min = 8, scheme = Password.Scheme.ALPHA_NUMERIC_MIXED_CASE)
@BindView(R.id.password)
TextInputEditText password;

@BindView(R.id.btn_sign_in)
Button signInButton;

private SignInInteractionListener signInInteractionListener;
private FieldValidate fieldValidate;
private FieldValidate.ValidationListener validationListener;

public static SignInWithEmailAndPasswordFragment newInstance() {
    SignInWithEmailAndPasswordFragment signInWithEmailAndPasswordFragment = new SignInWithEmailAndPasswordFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    signInWithEmailAndPasswordFragment.setArguments(args);
    return signInWithEmailAndPasswordFragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sign_in, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    setUpValidator();
}

@OnClick(R.id.sign_up)
protected void signUp() {
    signInInteractionListener.onSignUpOption();
}

@OnClick(R.id.restore_password)
protected void restorePassword() {

}

@OnClick(R.id.btn_sign_in)
protected void signIn() {
    fieldValidate.validate();
    if (validationListener.isValidated()) {
        String email = Objects.requireNonNull(this.email.getText()).toString();
        String password = Objects.requireNonNull(this.password.getText()).toString();

        Utils.hideKeyboardFromFragment(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()), getView());

        signInInteractionListener.onSignInWithEmail(email, password);
    }
}

@OnFocusChange({R.id.email, R.id.password})
protected void onFocusChange() {
    if (!email.isFocused() || !password.isFocused()) {
        Utils.hideKeyboardFromFragment(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()), getView());
    }
}

@OnTextChanged({R.id.email, R.id.password})
protected void onTextChanged() {
    if (email.isFocused()) emailContainer.setErrorEnabled(false);
    else if (password.isFocused()) passwordContainer.setErrorEnabled(false);
}

private void setUpValidator() {
    fieldValidate = new FieldValidate(this);
    validationListener = new FieldValidate.ValidationListener(getActivity());
    fieldValidate.setValidationListener(validationListener);
}


@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof SignInInteractionListener)
        signInInteractionListener = (SignInInteractionListener) context;
}

public interface SignInInteractionListener {
    void onSignInWithEmail(String email, String password);

    void onSignUpOption();
}}
```

Esta es la clase del Validator donde implemento `ValidatorListener`

```
public class FieldValidate extends Validator {

/**
 * Constructor.
 *
 * @param controller The class containing {@link View}s to be validated. Usually,
 *                   an {@link Activity} or a {@link Fragment}.
 */
public FieldValidate(Object controller) {
    super(controller);
}

public static class ValidationListener implements Validator.ValidationListener {

    private final Context context;
    private final int MAX_NUMBER_RULES = 2;
    private boolean validated;

    public ValidationListener(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onValidationSucceeded() {
        setValidated(true);
        Timber.d("Validation succeeded");
    }

    @Override
    public void onValidationFailed(List<ValidationError> errors) {
        setValidated(false);

        for (ValidationError error : errors) {
            View view = error.getView();

            String message = error.getCollatedErrorMessage(context);

            if (error.getFailedRules().size() == MAX_NUMBER_RULES &&
                    (message = error.getFailedRules().get(0).getMessage(context)) == null) {
                message = error.getFailedRules().get(1).getMessage(context);
            }

            if (view instanceof TextInputEditText) {
                ((TextInputLayout) view.getParent().getParent()).setError(message);
            }
        }

        Timber.d("Validation failed");
    }

    public boolean isValidated() {
        return validated;
    }

    public void setValidated(boolean validated) {
        this.validated = validated;
    }
}}
```

Investigando encontré que con `@Pattern` tal vez pueda crear ese mensaje personalizado, pero aun no se como, ya que no hay demasiada información.

Agradezco la ayuda que me puedan brindar

Esta es la Organizacion de la base de datos dentro de Firestore

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, como que no hay un dato en la base de datos :D, me podrias dar un ejemplo porque creo que es sensillo :D

Comment: Hola, por ejemplo, quiero comprobar en el registro que el documento de identidad no exista en la base de datos, o el correo. Si yo me estoy registrando e ingreso un documento de identidad que ya esta en la base de datos, debo mostrar un mensaje de alerta, para decirle al usuario que debe ingresar otro porque ese ya existe.

Comment: pero tendrias que llamar a firebase, te pondre una solucion :D pero es con llamada a firebase.

Comment: Si, me puede servir, gracias.

Comment: El email donde lo guardas en la base de datos no ?, podrias mostrar en una imagen la estructura de tu bd para mostrarte como se haria?

Comment: Si, acabo de actualizar la pregunta con una imagen

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88463/discussion-between-carlosgub-and-loperso).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te podria ayudar a realizar lo siguiente.
Pd: lo modificare cuando tenga la imagen de la estructura de tu BD

```
CollectionReference docRef = db.collection("user");
Query query = docRef.whereEqualTo("email", "PON TU EMAIL ACA"); //Aca pon el email
query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (documentSnapshot != null) {
            if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                 //Si existe el correo
            } else {
                 //No existe el correo
            }
        } 
   }
});
```

Para mas informacion podrias revisar esto https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data?hl=es-419

Comment: Si me funcionó, lo único era que me salia error debido a que al comienzo no es `docRef.get()`... Si no `query.get()`... y cambie de DocumentSnapshot a QuerySnapshot, ahi todo me funcionó. Muchas Gracias :D

Comment: Modificare la respuesta. Podrias poner como resuelto :D